# error with ido.el emacs : Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable <html)

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I was installing some packages from marmalade and when I reboot my emacs I receive this error, I can't uninstall those using marmalade again, I run emacs in debug mode and this is the error:

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable <html)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<3>> nil "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/ido.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 32
load-with-code-conversion("c:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/ido.el" "c:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/ido.el" nil t)
ido-mode(t)
sublime-setup-go-to-anything()
sublime-activate()
byte-code("\300 \210\301\302!\207" [sublime-activate provide sublime-emacs] 2)
(sublime-activate)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "c:/Documents and Settings/Carlos/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/elpa/sublime-0.0.3/sublime-autoloads.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2445
load-with-code-conversion("c:/Documents and Settings/Carlos/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/elpa/sublime-0.0.3/sublime-autoloads.el" "c:/Documents and Settings/Carlos/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/elpa/sublime-0.0.3/sublime-autoloads.el" nil t)
load("c:/Documents and Settings/Carlos/Datos de programa/.emacs.d/elpa/sublime-0.0.3/sublime-autoloads" nil t)
```

Apparently the mistake is the beginning the ido.el file, the tag xml is the problem cause but I don't know how fix this... My ido file begin with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>                   

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="Loggerhead/1.18 Python/2.6.5 Bazaar/2.3.3 Paste/1.7.2 PasteDeploy/1.3.3 SimpleTAL/4.1 Pygments/1.4 simplejson/2.1.3" name="generator" />
<title>~vcs-imports/emacs/trunk : contents of lisp/ido.el at revision 104584</title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.el` file extension stands for Emacs Lisp, and so the contents of any such file should be lisp. To find XML content suggests that something has gone rather wrong in the obtaining of that file.

I would suspect that a request to fetch a file over HTTP met an error from the web server, and you have ended up with an XHTML error page instead of the real file.

The `sublime-0.0.3` package is most likely broken, and the best course of action would be to remove it. You could start by just deleting that directory entirely; hopefully package.el will handle that gracefully.

After that I would try installing the package again. If the same thing happens, then perhaps the package was actually uploaded in this broken state, and you should contact the maintainer to let them know that it needs fixing.